# Create columns based on multiple other columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create multiple other columns based on three columns in my data (`Company`, `Name`, and `Year`).

I want to create multiple columns which give me the output as displayed in the table below. The following are the criteria for each column I want to create.

*`Number_Years:`* Number of years a person has worked with the company.
*`7years_Span:`* Number of years a person has worked with the company in the last 7 years (from the current year).
*`Continuous_Years:`* Number of continuous years a person has worked with the company.
*`Years_Gap:`* Number of years between that last time Person worked with the company and joining the company again.

**Based on the columns *`Company`, `Name`* and *`Year`*: I want to create other columns as defined above**

| Company | Name | Year | Number_Years | 7years_Span | Continuous_Years | Years_Gap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | John | 2002 | 7 | 1 | 3 | 0 |
| ABC | John | 2003 | 7 | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| ABC | John | 2004 | 7 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| ABC | Dave | 2005 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| ABC | John | 2006 | 7 | 4 | 1 | 1 |
| ABC | Dave | 2007 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| ABC | John | 2008 | 7 | 5 | 2 | 1 |
| ABC | John | 2009 | 7 | 5 | 2 | 0 |
| BBC | Jim | 2010 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| ABC | Jim | 2010 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| BBC | Dave | 2011 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| BBB | John | 2011 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| ABC | Jim | 2011 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| ABC | John | 2012 | 7 | 4 | 1 | 2 |

I have tried to create these columns but I have gotten nowhere near so far and I have searched on StackOverflow and other platforms with no luck. Would appreciate it if anyone can help. I hope I have provided a simple example with enough information.

**Example data dput:**

```
structure(list(Company = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("ABC", "BBB", "BBC"
), class = "factor"), Name = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Dave", "Jim", 
"John"), class = "factor"), Year = c(2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2012L), Number_Years = c(7L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 7L), `7years_span` = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L), Continuous_Years = c(3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), Years_Gap = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

Comment: Please provide code for your dataframe. You can use `dput(dataframe)`

Comment: What do you mean by 'current year'? The last year? 2021?

Comment: "Years_Gap: Number of years between that last time Person worked with the company.". between the last time the person worked with the company AND WHAT?

Comment: @GuedesBF Thanks for your consideration. By 'current year' I mean if being calculated from, say, 2004, then consider previous 7 years starting from 2004 and backward as opposed to from 2003 and backward.

For the second clarification, the number of years between the last time Person worked with the company and then again joining the company to work with them. So basically the gap since last working for the company and then again joining.

Comment: why `ABC + John` for 2008 & 2009 `continuous years` is `1`?  Shouldn't it be 2?

Comment: @AnilGoyal You are right! My mistake. I will correct it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited**

```r
df <- structure(list(Company = c("ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", 
                                 "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "BBC", "ABC", "BBC", "BBB", "ABC", "ABC"
), Name = c("John", "John", "John", "Dave", "John", "Dave", "John", 
            "John", "Jim", "Jim", "Dave", "John", "Jim", "John"), Year = c(2002L, 
                                                                           2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2010L, 
                                                                           2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2012L)), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = "data.frame")
df
#>    Company Name Year
#> 1      ABC John 2002
#> 2      ABC John 2003
#> 3      ABC John 2004
#> 4      ABC Dave 2005
#> 5      ABC John 2006
#> 6      ABC Dave 2007
#> 7      ABC John 2008
#> 8      ABC John 2009
#> 9      BBC  Jim 2010
#> 10     ABC  Jim 2010
#> 11     BBC Dave 2011
#> 12     BBB John 2011
#> 13     ABC  Jim 2011
#> 14     ABC John 2012
library(runner)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Company, Name) %>%
  mutate(Number_years = n(),
         X7Years_span = runner(x = Year,
                               k = 7,
                               idx = Year,
                               f = function(x) length(x)),
         Continous_years = cumsum(c(0, diff(Year)) != 1),
         Years_gap = Year - lag(Year, default = first(Year) -1) -1) %>%
  group_by(Continous_years, .add = T) %>%
  mutate(Continous_years = n()) %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 14 x 7
#>    Company Name   Year Number_years X7Years_span Continous_years Years_gap
#>    <chr>   <chr> <int>        <int>        <int>           <int>     <dbl>
#>  1 ABC     John   2002            7            1               3         0
#>  2 ABC     John   2003            7            2               3         0
#>  3 ABC     John   2004            7            3               3         0
#>  4 ABC     Dave   2005            2            1               1         0
#>  5 ABC     John   2006            7            4               1         1
#>  6 ABC     Dave   2007            2            2               1         1
#>  7 ABC     John   2008            7            5               2         1
#>  8 ABC     John   2009            7            5               2         0
#>  9 BBC     Jim    2010            1            1               1         0
#> 10 ABC     Jim    2010            2            1               2         0
#> 11 BBC     Dave   2011            1            1               1         0
#> 12 BBB     John   2011            1            1               1         0
#> 13 ABC     Jim    2011            2            2               2         0
#> 14 ABC     John   2012            7            4               1         2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Much better than my answer. Good job.

Comment: I am not clear on `continuous year` calculation

Comment: Yes, it still need some clarification from the OP.
I think you may need something like `max()` here, not so sure how to group by all 'streaks'.
`.....Continous_years = max(streak_run(Continous_years))....`

Comment: Thank you @AnilGoyal, this is very helpful! @GuedesBF, I will try the max approach on `continuous year`. Have a good day both!

Comment: @FurqanShah, see edited answer.  It now matches exactly with the expected output